# openshift piwik quickstart

Tags: openshift, matomo

I tried deploying piwik on OpenShift through their web-based quickstart.  It installs fine but when I click through the configuration steps via the newly created site, it fails on the 2nd step:

Error: PHP version > 5.3.3 required

However the system also reports that the version of PHP installed is 5.3.3

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the QuickStart to use PHP 5.4 and MySQL 5.5. Try again now :)

Here's the link to the updated QuickStart on OpenShift Hub: https://github.com/openshift/piwik-openshift-quickstart